# Setting up Firebase in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate firebase in my android app. I have downloaded `google-services.json` file from firebase console, added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in my `project/build.gradle`. I have also added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in my `app/build.gradle`. I am using google play services version 9.2.1. However, when I sync project files with gradle, I get following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

If i change version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0, it sync successfully, however when I run my app, I get following error:

```
A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4680)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4613)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058) 
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4680) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4613) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here are my dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
```

Can anyone guide me as to how can I use firebase along with google play services version 9.2.1????

Comment: Can you please include your dependencies here?

Comment: added. @ShobhitPuri

Comment: What is wrong with following the Firebase documentation? I think you are missing some Firebase dependencies from there

Comment: Can you please tell what am I missing?? @cricket_007

Comment: did you add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' to your gradle ? also make sure your support Repository is update (in SDK manager I mean)

Comment: Sorry, I trust your ability to search for the Firebase setup android guide on your own

Comment: I did everything mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup @cricket_007

Comment: I have android support repository version 35.0.0 installed. Is there any further update available?? @Amir

Comment: I don't think you did. `firebase-core:9.2.1`  is not in the code of your question

Comment: I added it as well. However, still i am getting same "version conflict" error. @cricket_007

Comment: Well, what do you think "version conflict" means? All Firebase versions must match the GMS versions, for the most part

Comment: yes. you are right! Thanks man for the help! @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to use

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
```

with

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1' ?
```

The 9.2.1 version of firebase can be uses as of July 14.

Comment: Ok  did you add the line

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

at the end of your gradle file ? I tried with my own project if i have this line at the top i got a conflict.

Comment: which lines buddy??

Comment: Okay. I also added it at the top. Let me try adding it at the bottom.

Comment: Hey, it worked man! Gradle sync successful. Also, I got rid of the error!!! Thanks a ton man! You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Google Play services 9.0.1 release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90):

> Fixes a class change compilation error with ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir().

Update all of the Google Play services and Firebase dependencies to use version 9.0.1 or higher if you want to use version 24.0.0 or higher of the Android Support Library.